# What's the purpose of the tagline in the Bounties section of the profile?

Tags: discussion, bounty, profile-page

This struck me as rather odd. The Bounties section of any given profile, for any of the three tabs (active, offered and earned), contains a list of post links with the amount of rep of the bounty in question. It also has a tagline that indicates, as far as I can tell, the same 'activity' link that's on the front page.

[image]

I find this a weird place for such a link. If A awarded B a bounty, I'm not really that interested in whether C or D edited their answer later on. I'm more interested in when the bounty was awarded and links to B (resp. A) on A (resp. B)'s profile. (To the extent I'm interested in anything on that row, that is.)

Is there some specific rationale for this? Or is this just standard code for question lookup?

Comment: Happy for this to be migrated to Mother Meta if deemed appropriate.

Comment: I assume you check for this on mother meta already?

Comment: Had a brief look but I'll happily stand corrected if I missed it. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99915/could-the-date-a-bounty-was-offered-be-added-to-the-profile-page) is weirdly inconsistent with the current profile page.

Comment: That post and resolution also didn't seem to be the same. I mean, I don't understand how the resolution addressed the OP request or issue. Nothing about this makes sense anymore

Comment: +1 vote to upgrade this to mother meta

Comment: Cross-posted to meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248156/whats-the-purpose-of-the-tagline-in-the-bounties-section-of-the-profile).